# Not sure how to implement some NServiceBus features in Orleans/Service Fabric

Tags: nservicebus, azure-service-fabric, orleans

I know this are two different systems for a bit different purposes, but to some extent in some situations they could serve the same goals, and I wonder how easy it would be to migrate some of our services from NServiceBus (NSB) to Orleans or MS Service Fabric. I invested several hours into learning on a high-level what Orleans and MS Service Fabric are, but some questions are left unanswered. May I list some NSB features I want to keep in the migration and I hope you could tell if Orleans or Service Fabric support something like that:

1. In NSB we can set maximum amount of threads the service is
   supposed to run under, so that we can prioritize services with low
   latency over less critical services with high latency. Can I
   configure maximum amount of instances on a single or multiple app
   servers specific Orlean’s grain is supposed to run under? I’m
   talking about grains with different ids
2. Some of our services are dependent of third-party services calls
   which could be temporarily unavailable. In the case exception is
   thrown and message run through configured amount of retries. If all
   further attempts to handle the message are over (service still
   unavailable), the message is put into error queue where we can see
   it and reprocess at any time when third-party service is back on
   track. I know we can implement additional tools on top of Orleans to
   have a similar system, but do Orleans or MS Service Fabric provide
   something out of the box in terms of message retries and failed
   message/calls storage in a special place or under special state?
3. In a rare events when our system is overloaded with incoming messages initiated by clients, messages are
   stuck in incoming queue, and system takes whatever it can take to handle, and all the
   rest messages are waiting for turn get handled according to “first
   come – first served” principle. I guess Orleans cannot cover this
   requirement as it sounds more like a pure queuing concept,
   but just in case maybe
   someone will have an idea on how it could be migrated to Orleans,
   like integration to some sort of queuing system

Comment: Would you like to jump on a call with me? I'm experienced with Service Fabric and Orleans as well as NServiceBus because I work for Particular Software. If yes shoot me an email to daniel dot marbach at particular dot net

Answer (score 1):

Orleans or Service Fabric *Reliable Actors*: These are similar solutions for (virtual) actors but with different trade-offs. https://richorama.github.io/2016/07/08/orleans-vs-service-fabric/

Orleans and Service Fabric *Stateless Service*: You can run Orleans over SF, you get both the Orleans version of virtual actors and the elasticity of SF.

NServiceBus vs Orleans (note: I have only very basic knowledge of NServiceBus): NServiceBus comes from the stateless world where you persist messages to provide reliability, Orleans comes from the stateful world, where you persist actors state for reliability. Yes, there are Sagas in NServiceBus and Streams in Orleans, so you can implement anything anywhere, though these are different approaches that (should) impact your architectural design.

Answer 1: Orleans grains (actors) are not services, thousands, millions, billions of grains give you a service. So you can't fine tune the scheduling between grains. An Orleans grain is not a handler of all the messages of type T, usually you have a large number of grains, grains are more like an object than a class.

Answer 2, 3: You can implement these incoming and outgoing message queues with Orleans streams (this is basically a good concept), though Orleans doesn't give you out-of-the-box solutions for your error queues, reprocessing, etc. But an Orleans stream is not a simple queue, usually you have a large number of streams, streams are a runtime changeable communication graph of grains, as the number of grains is large, so as the number of streams also. As Orleans gives you the async/await abstraction instead of dealing with low level bidirectional messaging between grains, the streams are abstraction for multiple one way messages.

Answer (score 0):

NServiceBus endpoints can perfectly be hosted inside Service Fabric. If you opt for stateless hosting nothing changes really. See the sample https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/hosting/service-fabric-hosting/ that shows how to set up hosting in Service Fabric